# При подключении к базе данных выдаёт ошибку Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть код

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli !';
} else {
    echo 'We have connection!';
}
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test'); //line 7
$query = $db -> query("SELECT name FROM 'test'");
$result = $connection -> query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['name'] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

При выполнении кода получаю

**We don't have mysqli !
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\Users\Vit\PhpstormProjects\untitled\index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Vit\PhpstormProjects\untitled\index.php on line 7**

В строке `$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');`
у меня всё правильно. Также в XAMPP запущен Apache и Mysql. В чём может быть ещё проблема??

Comment: Он же пишет тебе, класс не найден

Comment: что то надо установить ещё, пакет какой-то?

Comment: Да, mysqli, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Comment: В странном месте он у тебя ищет mysqli, а ты настройки в php.ini не трогал ? например модули где смотреть по умолчанию ?

Comment: настройки в php.ini не трогал...у меня в php.ini раскомментировано extension=php_mysqli.dll , получается что эта библиотека есть?

Comment: настройки в php.ini не трогал

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52160/discussion-between-sven-and-orange-shadow).

Comment: Очень частая ошибка, люди забывают перегрузить сервер, при включение нового модуля. Для проверки самый надежный способ, откройте файл с  `<?php php_info();` в нем и посмотрите, что за модули подгружены и правильный ли `php.ini` грузит.

Comment: ^ `<?php phpinfo();` :)